# use library in android library project and avoid dependency issue for my consumer

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am working on a project and so far in order to provide minimal integration effort for my consumers, I was forced to use all core Android framework APIs. That being said, I did not use any additional dependencies although there are alot of android library available out there to make my life easier. But recently I've been thinking about using [Android annotation library](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations.html). and in order to use it the docs ask me to include them into the project.

`dependencies { compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.0' }`

From my knowledge, this will make my consumers forced to downland the libraries(they might not need) when they use my library. Can anyone please let me know if there is any better practice to achieve that not to include the library for my consumer but only my own project scope?

---

UPDATED:

I think I just found those two lines from the official docs.

`If you use annotations in your own library module, the annotations are included as part of the Android Archive (AAR) artifact in XML format in the annotations.zip file. Adding the support-annotations dependency does not introduce a dependency for any downstream users of your library.`

But I am still curious about general dependency issue and how to handle the dependencies if we are just a library.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is OK to make the library you depend on available to the user of your library.
If several libraries require a popular dependency, it's better to have the code included just once, if you want to reduce your apk size.
Also, if the user of your library doesn't want to include the transitive dependency, an [exclude option](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:exclude_transitive_dependencies) can be added to the dependency declaration.

Other case is when you hapen to provide several libraries, where you can also [ensure that the transitive dependency has the same version among your libraries](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:dependency_resolve_rules)

In other words, I would let the users the power to decide if they want the transitive dependency or not.